# Can i change the contents of a script tag that is declared in the head section of HTML using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to change the contents of the script tag that is declared in the head section of my html page using

```
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="document.write('abc')";
```

is it possible to do so?
because i am not seeing any results

my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="a2" >

</script>
</head>
<body>
hello !
<script type="text/javascript">
var result;
$.ajax( {
type:'Get',
url:'http://172.27.140.52/cgi-bin/lockdownsubscribe.cgi',
success:function(data) {
if(data=='Locked')
{
document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML="document.write('a1 change')";
//document.write("hello world");
}
// alert(data);
//document.write(data);
//result = data;
}

})

//document.write(data);
//document.write(result);
</script>
<p id="a1">
change
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

~
~

Comment: What problem do you hope to solve by doing this thing?

Comment: I have a webpage with lots of javascript that was handed to me by my predecessor at work. I have to change a part of that javascript dynamically based on my result from a cgi script.

so .. I was trying this trial implementation. @Pointy

Comment: Ummm ya.  Why would you need to do this? o.O

Comment: You don't have any element with id of `a`.

Comment: `document.write` (to my knowledge) is erroneous in a `<head>` script tag anyways.

Comment: Changing the contents of the `<script>` block is pointless. The browser will have already evaluated it all, and it won't do it again.

Comment: I don't think you need to change the js dynamically.  Just write proper javascript that does what it's supposed to do based on what's on the page, or based on the response from the CGI script?

Comment: oh ok. I am trying to modify the script as well. just thought if this works out it'd reduce the stratin !